# I want to set my variable value like this

Tags: python

I'm coding a function visualization program in Processing in Python 3.x
How can I set variable value from a string, like I want.
Here's how i would like to set it:

```
fnc = "sin(x)"

y = some_function_to_do_this(fnc)

y = sin(x)
```

Is there any solution for this problem, or unfortunately I have to forget it away!

Comment: Read docs about `eval`.

Comment: check [exec()](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html)

Comment: As a follow up to the previous two comments, `eval` and `exec` are very insecure and should not be used if the input comes from an untrusted source

Comment: Consider whether you really want your program to allow users to indicate `fnc = "import os; for root, _, fnames in os.walk('/'): for fname in fnames: os.remove(os.path.join(root, fname))"` and wipe their whole system.

Comment: or just `"os.system('format C:')"`

Comment: @AdamSmith I advise against actually writing the malicious commands, you wouldn't believe how many people will just copy and paste that out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using exec(), like this:

```
fnc = "print('hi')"
y=exec(fnc)
```